# Make File Optional Options

Tags: makefile

i'm just creating my very first Makefile and would need some help:

`make foobar stefan`

expected:
i'd need the "stefan" in a variable to work with it - is there any way for it?

thanks,
Stefan

Comment: Your question is not clear, but I believe the answer is "no", at least not written like that.  Make is not a general-purpose interpreter where you can define your own uses of the command line: it's a tool which has a specific interpretation of the arguments in the command line, and you can't change that.  Every non-option argument is either a target to be built (`foobar`, `stefan`) or a variable assignment (`FOOBAR=stefan`).  If you want `stefan` in a variable, you have to use the latter syntax.  See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Overriding.html

Comment: alright, thanks - thought i've overseen something from the docs!